# Problema ao comparar 2 listas

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Estou com um problema, preciso fazer um filtro com uma Lista de strings que vem como parametro com um `icollection`, o visual studio acusa

> "Cannot convert from List to UnidadeFederativaFornecedor"

O que poderia ser feito neste caso? Este é o codigo:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetPotenciaisFornecedoresProduto(int id, [FromUriAttribute] List<int> marcas, int dias, List<string> unfed ,int? take = 20, int skip = 0)
    {
        DateTime dataDaOperacao = DateTime.Now;
        dataDaOperacao = dataDaOperacao.AddDays(-dias);



        var ofertas = FornecedorCotacaoService.GetAll()
            .Where(c => c.FornecedorProdMarcaCotacao.Any(o => o.ProdutoMarca.IdProduto == id
                                                      && (marcas.Contains(o.ProdutoMarca.IdMarca)
                                                      && (c.Cotacao.DtCadastro >= dataDaOperacao)
                                                      && *c.Fornecedor.UnidadeFederativaFornecedor.Contains(unfed)*)
                  ))
            .GroupBy(c => new { c.IdFornecedor, c.Fornecedor.Pessoa.NmPessoa, c.Fornecedor.Pessoa.EnderecoFatura.IdUnidadeFederativa })
            .Select(c => new { c.Key.IdFornecedor, c.Key.NmPessoa, c.Key.IdUnidadeFederativa, Count = c.Count() })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: se você olhar na documentação vai ver que o contains está da seguinte maneira List<T>.Contains(T) , sendo o 'T' o tipo em questão, observe que no seu caso você está pegando uma lista do tipo UnidadeFederativaFornecedor e esta tentando usar contains com uma lista de strings

Comment: Alguma sugestão do que poderia ser feito ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ponto em questão, você poderia usar um .Any no lugar do .Contains, e dentro do .Any usar o Contains para verificar sua string.

```
&& c.Fornecedor.UnidadeFederativaFornecedor.Any(uff => undef.Contains(uff.PropriedadeStringQueRepresentaUNDEF))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo!!